# Need to display random list of 6 authors

Tags: php, wordpress, function

there -- I have been able to get pretty far on this function I adapted for https://annexteenclinic.org; however, instead of pulling in 6 authors of the 20 or so authors on the site randomly, it displays the first 6 alphabetically in random order.

Obviously, I am missing something! I am curious to know how I can tweak the code below to pull a random 6 authors, and then display them. Thanks in advance for your thoughts. Would welcome ideas on how to make this code tidier. It is sprawling.

```
function stahom() {
    $display_admins = false;
    //$order_by = 'display_name';
    // 'nicename', 'email', 'url', 'registered', 'display_name', or 'post_count'
    $order_by = 'rand';
    $order = 'ASC';
    $role = 'staff-directory'; // 'subscriber', 'contributor', 'editor', 'author' - leave blank for 'all'
    $hide_empty = false; // hides authors with zero posts
    $number = '6';

    if (!empty($display_admins)) {
        $blogusers = get_users('orderby='.$order_by.'&role='.$role);
    } else {
        $admins = get_users('role=administrator');
        $exclude = array();

        foreach ($admins as $ad) {
            $exclude[] = $ad->ID;
        }

        $exclude = implode(',', $exclude);
        $blogusers = get_users('exclude='.$exclude.'&orderby='.$order_by.'&number='.$number.'&order='.$order.'&role='.$role);
    }

    $authors = array();

    foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
        $user = get_userdata($bloguser->ID);

        if (!empty($hide_empty)) {
            $numposts = count_user_posts($user->ID);
            if ($numposts < 1) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        $authors[] = (array) $user;
    }

    shuffle($authors);
    array_rand($authors);
    foreach ($authors as $author) {
        $author_title = get_field('title', 'user_'. $author['ID']);
        $display_name = $author['data']->display_name;
        $author_profile_url = get_author_posts_url($author['ID']);

        $author_regpho = get_field('regpho', 'user_'. $author['ID']);
        $regurl = $author_regpho['url'];

        $author_hovpho = get_field('hovpho', 'user_'. $author['ID']);
        $hovurl = $author_hovpho['url'];

        $size = 'thumbnail';
        $regthumb = $author_regpho['sizes'][$size];
        $hovthumb = $author_hovpho['sizes'][$size];

        echo '<div class="third"><div class="container"><a href="', $author_profile_url, '" class="contributor-link"><img src="', $regthumb,'" alt="', $display_name,'" class="image">';
        echo '<div class="overlay">';
        echo '<img src="', $hovthumb,'" alt="', $display_name,'" class="image"></div>';
        echo '</a></div>';
        echo '<div class="stalin"><a href="', $author_profile_url, '" class="contributor-link">', $display_name, '<br/><span>', $author_title, '</a></span></div></div>';
    }
}
add_action('hook_bottom_stahom', 'stahom');
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `$number = '6';` to 20?

Comment: Either get rid of `'&number='.$number` in the query so you get all and then slice 6 before your loop, or fix the `order_by` as it doesn't seem to be working, maybe `rand()`, or maybe it's `order` and not `order_by` not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for the suggestions, all. I took your advice and I am posting the code below. What I did was get rid of the number limit and then added the slice to the first six randomly pulled as suggested. Here is the result and IT WORKS! Appreciate the help!

```
function stahom() {
?>
<?php
 $display_admins = false;
 //$order_by = 'display_name';
 // 'nicename', 'email', 'url', 'registered', 'display_name', or 'post_count'
 $order_by = 'rand';
 $order = 'ASC';
 $role = 'staff-directory'; // 'subscriber', 'contributor', 'editor', 'author' - leave blank for 'all'
 $hide_empty = false; // hides authors with zero posts

 if(!empty($display_admins)) {
      $blogusers = get_users('orderby='.$order_by.'&role='.$role);
 } else {
    $admins = get_users('role=administrator');
    $exclude = array();

    foreach($admins as $ad) {
      $exclude[] = $ad->ID;
    }

    $exclude = implode(',', $exclude);
    $blogusers = get_users('exclude='.$exclude.'&orderby='.$order_by.'&number='.$number.'&order='.$order.'&role='.$role);
 }

 $authors = array();

 foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
    $user = get_userdata($bloguser->ID);

    if(!empty($hide_empty)) {
        $numposts = count_user_posts($user->ID);
        if($numposts < 1) continue;
    }

    $authors[] = (array) $user;
 }

 shuffle($authors);$authors = array_slice( $authors, 0, 6 );array_rand($authors);foreach($authors as $author) {
    $author_title = get_field('title', 'user_'. $author['ID']);
    $display_name = $author['data']->display_name;
    $author_profile_url = get_author_posts_url($author['ID']);

    $author_regpho = get_field('regpho', 'user_'. $author['ID']);
    $regurl = $author_regpho['url'];

    $author_hovpho = get_field('hovpho', 'user_'. $author['ID']);
    $hovurl = $author_hovpho['url'];

    $size = 'thumbnail';
    $regthumb = $author_regpho['sizes'][ $size ];
    $hovthumb = $author_hovpho['sizes'][ $size ];

    echo '<div class="third"><div class="container"><a href="', $author_profile_url, '" class="contributor-link"><img src="', $regthumb,'" alt="', $display_name,'" class="image">';
    echo '<div class="overlay">';
    echo '<img src="', $hovthumb,'" alt="', $display_name,'" class="image"></div>';
    echo '</a></div>';
    echo '<div class="stalin"><a href="', $author_profile_url, '" class="contributor-link">', $display_name, '<br/><span>', $author_title, '</a></span></div></div>';
}

?>
<?php
}
add_action('hook_bottom_stahom', 'stahom');
```